# Vertically centering Font Awesome icon inside nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, centering

I'm trying to make the icon vertically centered so it would align with the rest of the nav links but I can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <img src="img/logo.png" class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><span class="fa fa-phone"> +62 202 555 0117</span></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav.navbar {
padding: 12px;
}
span.fa.fa-phone {
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: css `vertical-align: -25%` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Navbar's links have `padding: 15px` property. So you need to apply this property to the phone number.
2. Make special class for this purpose. Use

   `<li class="phone"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span> +62 202 555 0117</li>`

   instead of `<li><span class="fa fa-phone"> +62 202 555 0117</span></li>`.
3. Use `<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>`
   instead of `<img src="img/logo.png" class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">`
4. The toggle-button has to use the `id` from `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">` as the value of the `data-target` property.

Please chaeck the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.navbar {
  padding: 12px;
}
.nav .phone {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="phone"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span> +62 202 555 0117</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot.